# How to add a menu under Webform Results?

Tags: views, webforms, routes

In Drupal 7, I know we can use Views to add sub menu or menu tab on "My Workbench". The form result I have in "mydomain.com/node/99/webform-results" contained Submissions, Analysis, Table, Download, and Clear sub-menus. How can I add another sub menu next to "Submission"? I have tried to use the same method from Workbench, but it does not seem to work.

**My new sub-menu setting in Views**

```
Type: page
path: /node/99/webform-results/details
menu: Menu Tab: Navigation
```

Comment: Path should be `node/%/webform-results/details`, No?

Comment: You are right @Sumit Madan, but I only want to apply to that specific form. I want to show a field that only this form has.

Comment: Try selecting : `Default menu tab` instead of `Menu tab`.

Comment: Changing to “Default menu tab” does work, but I have to recreate all other tab menu and sub-menus, because the “Parent menu item: already exists” does not work on this situation. Can you post your answer below so we can close this issue? ty @Sumit Madan.

Comment: Glad it helps. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select `Default menu tab` instead of `Menu tab`.